# Javascript - Is there an easier way to read obfuscated, condensed code?

Tags: javascript, console, naming-conventions, obfuscation, deobfuscation

Is the code below an example of obfuscation? Is there a way to make code that has been obfuscated easier to interpret or follow the actions that lead through the script using chrome or firefox browsers? Are the original naming conventions somewhere behind the scenes? In other words, could I de-obfuscate the code short of downloading a couple hundred lines and then renaming everything based on what I think is happening?

```
main: function (a, b, c, d, e) {
    var r,
        o,
        s = null != t ? t : {
        },
        l = i.helperMissing,
        c = 'function',
        d = e.escapeExpression;
```

Comment: Looks more *minified* than deliberately obfuscated. Best thing to do would be to try to find the source, if at all possible (without that, there's no way to recover the original variable names)

Comment: Try to look for a ( source ) .map file for the code.. If it exists, you can use that to map the minified code to the source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That code is a result of minification and obfuscation which results in condensed code, and thus unreadable code. The entire point of minification is to reduce file size, so you the "real" function, attribute, and values aren't stored somewhere to be found. The idea of obfuscation is to make the code hard to decypher and "steal".

If you found this somewhere and the file ended in `.min.js`, you can always see if the same file exists in that location without the `.min` part in the filename.

For example

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js

Also, it would be near impossible for software to deobfuscate code, but you could read through it and try to understand its meaning. Here's a simple example

```
x=(a,b)=>a+b // obfuscated/minified code

function sum(number1, number2) { return number1 + number2 } // original code
```